# The movement of a particle

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The height $h$ of a particle which is moving in space is given by the relation 
$$z=h(x,y)=\sin(xy+\pi)$$
The coordinates $(x,y)$ of the particle varies depending on the time $t:x(t)=e^t$ and we can observe the value of $y(t)$:
$$y(0)=\pi \text{ and } y(0.25)=0$$

1. Give the change rate of the height in the direction $\vec{u}=\vec{i}+\vec{j}$ at position $(1,\pi)$.
2. Give the equation of the plane tangent at the surface define by $x=h(x,y)$ at the point $(1,\pi,0)$.
3. Estimate the speed at $t=0$ second.
4. Using the chain derivation, evaluate the expression $\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial{h}}{\partial{x}})$ at $t=0$.

Don't hesitate to correct my english, it's not my first language.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think I understand the 4th question, but I really don't understand the 1th question...

Comment: The real problem is I don't understand the question because I know the technics.

Comment: In the direction $\vec u$, you have $x=y$. Do you see why?

Comment: Not realy... And given this, what this is mean?

Comment: Your question 2. looks weird. Is it not $z=h(x,y)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Question 01

We have to calculate the directional derivative of $h(x,y)$ in the direction of $\vec{u}$.
\begin{align*}
D_{\vec{u}}h(x,y) &= \nabla{}h(x,y) \cdot \vec{u} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix} y\cos(xy + \pi) & x\cos(xy + \pi) \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \\
&= y\cos(xy + \pi) + x\cos(xy + \pi)
\end{align*}

Evaluate this directional derivative at the point $(1,\pi)$. 
\begin{align*}
D_{\vec{u}}h(1,\pi) &= \pi\cos(\pi + \pi) + \cos(\pi + \pi) \\
&= \pi + 1
\end{align*}

### Question 02

We want t find the equation of the tangent plane at the surface given by $z=h(x,y)$ at the point $(1,\pi,0)$.

First, calculate the parital derivative knowing that $f(x,y,z)=z-h(x,y)$.
\begin{align*}
f'_{x}=-y\cos(xy + \pi) && f'_{y}=-x\cos(xy + \pi) && \text{and} && f'_{z}=1
\end{align*}

After, we can define the equation of the tangent plane by definition.
\begin{align*}
f(x_0,y_0,z_0) && + && \begin{array}{rrr}f'_{x}(x_0,y_0,z_0)(x-x_0) \\ f'_{y}(x_0,y_0,z_0)(y-y_0) \\ f'_{z}(x_0,y_0,z_0)(z-z_0)\end{array} && = && 0
\end{align*}

And, we can replace the value in the definition.
\begin{align*}
-\sin(\pi + \pi) && + && \begin{array}{rrr}-\pi\cos(\pi + \pi)(x-1) \\ -\cos(\pi + \pi)(y - \pi) \\ (z-0)\end{array} && = && 0
\end{align*}

And, we simplify.
\begin{align*}
\pi_1 : \pi x +y-z=2\pi
\end{align*}

### Question 03

Calculate the partial derivative of the height by the time.
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial{h}}{\partial{t}}&=\frac{\partial{h}}{\partial{x}}\cdot\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{t}}+\frac{\partial{h}}{\partial{y}}\cdot\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{t}} \\
&= \frac{\partial{}}{\partial{x}}(\sin(xy+\pi))\cdot\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{t}} + \frac{\partial{}}{\partial{y}}(\sin(xy+\pi))\cdot\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{t}} \\
&= -\cos(xy)(yx'+xy')
\end{align*}

After, we can evaluate the derivative when $t=0$. And, we have to evaluate $x'(0)$ and $y'(0)$.
\begin{align*}
x'(0)=e^0=1 && \text{and} && y'(0)\approx\frac{y(0.25)-y(0)}{0.25}\approx -4\pi
\end{align*}

Then,
\begin{align*}
\left.\frac{\partial{h}}{\partial{t}}\right|_{t=0}\approx-(-1)(\pi-4\pi)\approx-3\pi
\end{align*}

### Question 04

First,
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial{h}}{\partial{x}}\right) &= \frac{d}{dt}(y\cos(xy+\pi))\\
&= -(y'\cos(xy)+y(yx'+xy')\cdot\sin(xy))
\end{align*}

And evaluate this expression when $t=0$.
\begin{align*}
\left.\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial{h}}{\partial{x}}\right)\right|_{t=0} &\approx -\left((-4\pi)\cos(\pi)+\pi(\pi-4\pi)\cdot\sin(\pi)\right)\approx4\pi
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

### Question 1

You're bascially moving from a $2$-d problem to a $1$-d problem. More specifically:
$\vec \nabla h(x,y) = (y\cos(xy +\pi), x \cos(xy + \pi))$

In the direction $(1,1)$, you're looking at $\vec \nabla h(x,y) \dot{} (1,1) = y\cos(xy +\pi) + x \cos(xy + \pi)$ At the point $(1,\pi)$, this is $\pi +1 $.

### Question 2

You need the take the gradient of the surface $z-h(x,y)$, which gives you a normal vector of $ (-y\cos(xy +\pi), -x \cos(xy + \pi, 1)$. Just plug the values to find the equation at the point you're given.

### Question 3

I don't think this can be solved without knowing what happens to $y(t)$.

### Question 4

Simple application of the chain rule, looks like you know what to do with it.